# Disable Table View Scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

Heres the problem:

I am presenting a popover tableview controller P on-top of an existing tableview controller E.

The issue I run into is E still scrolls.  Meaning if you scroll outside of the bounds of P, E will scroll and P will act as if it is apart of E.

How can I disable E from scrolling while P is presented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you present P, set:

`yourTableView.isScrollEnabled = false`

And when you close your popover:

`yourTableView.isScrollEnabled = true`

**Note: Maybe you will want to use a Protocol to enable the scroll again when you close your popover.**

For that, I would add in your popover View Controller:

```
protocol ProtocolPopOver{
  func enableScrollAgain();
}
```

Then, in that view controller:

```
var delegatePopOver:ProtoclPopOver?
```

And when you close your viewController:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { delegatePopOver.enableScrollAgain() })
```

In your main view controller, when you present the popover, add:

```
popoverViewController.delegatePopOver = self
```

Implement the protocol near UIViewController:

```
class yourclass: UIViewController, ProtocolPopOver{...
```

And add the function:

```
func enableScrollAgain(){
 yourTableView.isScrollEnable = true
}
```